# ¿Cómo graficar un polígono a partir de vértices definidos en un txt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

¿Cómo podría graficar un polígono en Python? Me dan ciertas coordenadas, puedo abrir el archivo y graficar sus vértices pero ¿Cómo los puedo unir?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data=pd.read_csv('poligono.txt',header=1,delim_whitespace=True)
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
x=data.iloc[:,0]
y=data.iloc[:,1]
#print(data)
plt.plot(x,y,"ro")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
```

***poligono.txt*** contiene:

```
    x     y
    3     4
   -3     2
    8     2
    2    -4
```

Necesito que quede tal cual la imagen del polígono:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existen paquetes que facilitan la tarea, como [shapely](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/) pero voy a dar una solución basada en pandas/NumPy, matplotlib y la biblioteca estándar solo.

Con matplotlib puedes hacer esto de diferentes formas por ejemplo usando `matplotlib.pyplot.fill` y `matplotlib.pyplot.Line2D` o usando [`matplotlib.patches.Polygon`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Polygon.html).

Un problema que hay que resolver es que en tus datos los vértices no tienen un orden adecuado, si intentamos graficar los vértices con ese orden nos podemos encontrar con algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una solución muy simple puede ser obtener el [centroide](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroide) y usarlo para ordenar los vértices de una forma correcta. El siguiente código nos permite graficar el polígono de tu ejemplo con un resultado muy similar al que muestras en la pregunta:

```
import itertools
import io
from string import ascii_uppercase
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker



def labels_gen():
    size = 1
    while True:
        for s in itertools.product(ascii_uppercase, repeat=size):
            yield "".join(s)
        size +=1



poligono = io.StringIO(
''' x     y
    3     4
   -3     2
    8     2
    2    -4

''')     


# Cargamos el csv
data = pd.read_csv(poligono, header=0, delim_whitespace=True)

# Cálculo del centroide
centroide = np.mean(data, axis=0)

# Cáculo del ángulo polar
aux = data - centroide
polar_angles = np.arctan2(aux.y, aux.x)

# Obtenemos un nuevo DataFrame con los vértices ordenados
data = data.reindex(polar_angles.argsort())


ax = plt.subplot(111)

# Creamos el polígono
plygon = plt.Polygon(data, fill=True, facecolor="#ffb3b3", edgecolor='#ff0000', alpha=1, zorder=1)
ax.add_patch(plygon)

# Creamos los vértices
ax.scatter(data.x, data.y, c='b', zorder=2)

# Etiquetas para cada vértice y arista
etiquetas = labels_gen()
for i, vertice in enumerate(data.values):
    lb = next(etiquetas)
    ax.annotate(s=lb, xy=vertice + 0.1)
    punto_medio = (vertice +  data.values[(i + 1) % (data.shape[0])]) / 2
    ax.annotate(s=lb.lower(), xy=punto_medio)

# Mostramos los ejes centrados en el origen
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

# Configuramos la rejilla
ax.grid(color='gray', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1, alpha=0.4)

# Escalamos la gráfica
ax.autoscale_view()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))

# Mostramos la gráfica
plt.show()
```

La implementación de las anotaciones para vértices y aristas no están muy pulidas, se pueden mejorar mucho para evitar solapamientos por ejemplo.

El resultado es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **Nota:** Al leer el csv usas `header=1`, lo cual usa la segunda fila del csv como cabezera, no la primera como debería ser en principio con el csv que muestras. A no ser que el csv tenga una fila vacía al principio debes usar `header=0`.

Comment: Gracias esta esta respuesta me ha sido de gran Utilidad! sos un genio!